# Scraping html page result.. not in the right order

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to get data from this page using `cheerio js`:

```
var html =
"<div class='clear'>" +
"<div class='time_head'>time_head content1</div>"
+ "<div class='blockfix'>blockfix1</div>"
+ "<div class='blockfix'>blockfix2</div>"
+ "<div class='time_head'>time_head content2</div>"
+ "<div class='blockfix'>blockfix3</div>"
+ "<div class='blockfix'>blockfix4</div>"
+ "<div class='blockfix'>blockfix5</div>"
+ "</div>";
```

this is what i tried so far:

```
$ = cheerio.load(html);
let devtoList = [];

$('.clear').each(function (i, elem) {
  devtoList[i] = {
    title: $(this).find('.time_head').text(),
    game: $(this).find('.blockfix').text()
  };
});
const devtoListTrimmed = devtoList.filter(n => n != undefined);
console.log(devtoListTrimmed);
```

the result is :

```
[ 
  { title: 'time_head content1time_head content2',
    game: 'blockfix1blockfix2blockfix3blockfix4blockfix5' } 
]
```

But i need every `time_head` with its `blockfix`'s

```
TIME_HEAD CONTENT1
   ----blockfix1
   ----blockfix2
TIME_HEAD CONTENT2
   ----blockfix3
   ----blockfix4
```

please note: 
   1- The number of `time_head`'s always change
   2- I'm open to other solutions

Comment: Instead of applying loop over `.clear` select `time_head`.

Comment: the result is empty using `time_head `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all elements with `.time_head`, iterate over it, apply while loop until the next element has class `blockfix`.

```js
const output = [];
$('.time_head').each(function(i) {
  let next = $(this).next('.blockfix');
  output.push({"title": $(this).text(), game: []});
  while(next) {
    output[i].game.push(next.text());
    const isNext = $(next).next('.blockfix');
    next = isNext.length > 0 ? $(next).next('.blockfix') : false;
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='clear'>
            <div class='time_head'>time_head content1</div>
            <div class='blockfix'>blockfix1</div>
            <div class='blockfix'>blockfix2</div>
            <div class='time_head'>time_head content2</div>
            <div class='blockfix'>blockfix3</div>
            <div class='blockfix'>blockfix4</div>
            <div class='blockfix'>blockfix5</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: perfect.. Thank you

Comment: please.. take a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118057/go-to-ejs-view-from-ejs-with-a-json-object